# Can't get widgets to showup on left nav bar with Fishpig

Tags: wordpress

I am using the newest version of the Fishpig extension. I have followed the instructions listed here

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/docs/widgets/

I have the TwentyTwelve Wordpress theme active and I don't have any of the old wordpress.xml files in my theme or the default theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ben was quick to help me, I used the existing sidebar from Wordpress and added this to my local.xml

```
<reference name="left">
   <block type="wordpress/sidebar" name="wordpress_sidebar_sidebar" as="wp.sidebar.left" before="-">
   <action method="setWidgetArea"><area>sidebar-2</area></action>
 </block>
</reference>
```